# Index out of range, for loop of deminishing nestled list

Tags: python

I am working in Dynamo where i'm trying to create a polyline from a number of selected connected lines. Since the selected lines will be created manually and selected into the grapg, these may be created in an uwanted order and orientation. I have therefore extracted the start- and endpoints of the lines and thereafter started to create a python-code to sort the points out in a desired order.

In dynamo:

I insert the Points into a nestled list, containing the start and endpoint of a line per sublist. I then locate the two Points that occur only once (since all the lines are connected there end points of the connected line will be retrieved). One of these Points will be selected as a starting Point for the ordering of all of the points.

In python:

I take the starting point and the nested list as inputs to the code and then try to sort the nestled list into an ordered nestled list. However, i am getting a warning that the index is out of range in my for loop and i can't seem to figure out why.

The issue occurs when i want to remove the pair of Points that i append into my ordered list from the original list. If this line is excluded i do get a value

I have tried some of the things mentioned in other posts t ono vail.

There also seem to be an issue with not only the range, but if I for instance have the input "scrambled", the loop does not check a nestled list that has been checked previously.

```
start = 0

l = [[1,0],[1,2],[4,3],[3,2]]

ordered = []

disordered = []


for i in range(len(l)):                     #loop for range from 0 to lenght of list -1
    for j in range(len(l[i])):              #loop for range from 0 to lenght of nested list -1
        if l[i][j] == start:                #Check which nested list contains start (Will allways be one in my case)
            disordered.append(l[i])         #Add that nested list to a temporary disordered list
            if disordered[0][0] == start:   #Check if the first value in the nested list is the same as the value 
                ordered.append(l[i])        #Add the nested list as is to the ordered list
                l.remove(l[i])              #Remove the nested list from original list
                disordered=[]               #Reset the temporary list
                start=ordered[-1][-1]       #Pick the new value to search for
            else:                           #If first value is not the same as the sought out value    
                ordered.append(l[i][::-1])  #Add the reversed nested list to the ordered list
                l.remove(l[i])              #Remove the nested list from original list
                disordered=[]               #Reset the temporary list
                start=ordered[-1][-1]       #Pick the new value to search for

print(ordered)                              #Output the ordered list
```

Expected result:

```
Input = [[1,0],[3,2],[1,2],[4,3]]

Output = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
```

Actual result:

```
Warning: IronPythonEvaluator.EvaluateIronPythonScript operation failed. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
IndexError: index out of range: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just use

```
sorted([sorted(i) for i in l], key=min)
```

your code get index error because you remove item from the list and try to access item by the original list indexes

If you don't want to use sorted you can change your code like this to work while you keep removing item from the list

```
    start = 0

l = [[1,0],[1,2],[4,3],[3,2]]

ordered = []

disordered = []

i = 0
while i < len(l):                           #loop for range from 0 to lenght of list -1
    j = 0
    while j < len(l[i]):                    #loop for range from 0 to lenght of nested list -1
        if l[i][j] == start:                #Check which nested list contains start (Will allways be one in my case)
            disordered.append(l[i])         #Add that nested list to a temporary disordered list
            if disordered[0][0] == start:   #Check if the first value in the nested list is the same as the value 
                ordered.append(l[i])        #Add the nested list as is to the ordered list
                l.remove(l[i])              #Remove the nested list from original list
                disordered=[]               #Reset the temporary list
                start=ordered[-1][-1]       #Pick the new value to search for
                i = -1                      #reset i
                break                       #move to the next point
            else:                           #If first value is not the same as the sought out value    
                ordered.append(l[i][::-1])  #Add the reversed nested list to the ordered list
                l.remove(l[i])              #Remove the nested list from original list
                disordered=[]               #Reset the temporary list
                start=ordered[-1][-1]       #Pick the new value to search for
                i = -1                      #reset i
                break                       #move to the next point
        j += 1
    i += 1

print(ordered)
```

Comment: I suspected that was the case, I tried appending in ["x","x"] just to keep the list index as well. But the issue of the scrambled input still persisted. I will give your suggestion a shot tomorrow.

In the mean time, cheers for the swift reply!

Edit: The input i have put in in the question is only for explanation - the real inputs will not be as trivial. It will be points that are in 3D, so using sorted will not suffice unfortunately. This is the reason why I try to find which nested list has a value equal to another one. the nested lists will always contain two values (start/endpoint).

Answer (score 0):

I have compleated the code. The main issue was using a for loop instead of a while loop. Needed some more tweaks ofc, but its all sorted out now.

Cheers for the response though, I appreciate it.